# Space over Navbar

Tags: html, css

I've got a question. I was trying to code a navbar. It's working perfectly except for the fact that over the navbar there is a big space. So that the navbar is in the middle of the page. I've got no clue what the mistake could be. If u got an idea of what the problem could be and how to solve it, I Would be very pleased. Otherwise, I would be happy to get improvement tips for my code.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .item-link {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: var(--white-smoke);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0e0e0e00;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .item-link:hover {
  background-color: var(--shadow);
  border: 1px solid #4e4e4e4d;
}

.navbar-nav .c:hover #drop-down {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav .c:focus-within #drop-down {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: var(--white-smoke);
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-10%);
  transform: translateX(-10%);
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks i {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks:hover {
  background-color: var(--shadow);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar #brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <title>DropDown Menu</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- Home -->
      <li class="nav-item h"><a href="#" class="item-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Categories -->
      <li class="nav-item c">
        <a href="#" class="item-link">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Investieren</a>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <div id="drop-down">
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> Web Development
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mobile Apps
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i> UI / UX
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i> Database
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i> Game Development
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Prices -->
      <li class="nav-item p"><a href="#" class="item-link">Prices</a>
      </li>
      <!-- About -->
      <li class="nav-item a"><a href="#" class="item-link">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have the `navbar` set to `top: 20%;`. You need to set it the fixed position to top 0%:

```
.navbar {
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%;
   right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: `left` and `right` values are unnecessary if `width: 100%;` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `top: 20%;` on your `.navbar` with fixed positioning. You also have `margin-top: 2px` on your `navbar`. Remove that and you should be good.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  /*top: 20%;*/
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  color: white;
  /*margin-top: 2px;*/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .item-link {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: var(--white-smoke);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0e0e0e00;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .item-link:hover {
  background-color: var(--shadow);
  border: 1px solid #4e4e4e4d;
}

.navbar-nav .c:hover #drop-down {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav .c:focus-within #drop-down {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: var(--white-smoke);
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-10%);
  transform: translateX(-10%);
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks i {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.navbar-nav .c #drop-down .clinks:hover {
  background-color: var(--shadow);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar #brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <title>DropDown Menu</title>
</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- Home -->
      <li class="nav-item h"><a href="#" class="item-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Categories -->
      <li class="nav-item c">
        <a href="#" class="item-link">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Investieren</a>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <div id="drop-down">
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> Web Development
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mobile Apps
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i> UI / UX
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i> Database
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="clinks"> <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i> Game Development
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Prices -->
      <li class="nav-item p"><a href="#" class="item-link">Prices</a>
      </li>
      <!-- About -->
      <li class="nav-item a"><a href="#" class="item-link">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have the `navbar` set to a fixed position with a top of 20%.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed; //this will make sure the navbar always stays in its position
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  top: 20%; //this is what is causing the "space" above
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--shadow);
    color:white;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

You're telling the navbar to go down 20% of the page with the top:20%. If you don't want the space, just remove the top: 20% and you should be fine.